# Organização de projetos com qMake

Tags: c++, qt, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e gostaria de começar a separar as coisas em partes menores e também para poder testar essas partes, então pesquisando encontrei algo sobre utilizar os arquivos *.pri para poder fazer uma cadeia de projetos e subprojetos, mas fiquei confuso como isso pode ser organizado e gostaria de alguma explicação mais acessível sendo que ainda sou iniciante na área.

Anteriormente os arquivos estavam todos dentro de:
 "myApp > core"

Organizei os arquivos e pastas da seguinte forma.
OBS: Apenas um exemplo, existem muitos arquivos para organizar.

```
├── core/
│   ├── myMath.h
│   ├── myMath.cpp
│   ├── quadTree.h
│   ├── quadTree.cpp
│   ├── bvh.h
│   ├── bvh.cpp
│   ├── myVec2.h
│   └── myVec2.cpp
├── gui/
│   ├── MainWindow.h
│   ├── MainWindow.cpp
│   ├── Explorer.h
│   ├── Explorer.cpp
│   └── gl/
│               ├── glView.h
│               ├── glView.cpp
│               ├── shaders/
│                          ├── vertex.vert
│                          └── fragment.frag
├── main.cpp
├── myApp.pro
├── Doxyfile
├── README.md
└── resources.qrc
```

Aparentemente eu preciso criar um arquivo *.pro tipo assim no root do projeto:
myApp.pro

---

TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
            core \
            gui \

---

Depois em cada folder eu devo criar um arquivo *.pri que lista os arquivos dentro desse folder.

---

HEADERS += \
            myMath.h \
            myVec2.h \

SOURCES += \
            myMath.cpp \
            myVec2.cpp \

---

Porém acontecem algumas situações que quero/preciso contornar.

Onde devo declarar o *.pro com as configs do myApp?
Ou seja o *.pro que deve conter as configs completas.
Hoje meu arquivo está mais ou menos assim https://pastebin.com/5msdv8YA

1º: Começar a separar os arquivos de implementação das coisas da interface gráfica, na questão dos arquivos, pois da implementação eu já faço isso, tento deixar a GUI o menos ligada ao código possível.

2º: Poder testar em partes menores o projeto.
Por exemplo: Criei uma classe math e preciso testar todas as funções e retornos. Para isso hoje eu crio um projeto separado e faço os testes e quando está aparentemente tudo bem eu jogo os arquivo lá no projeto final.

3º: É a mesma coisa que a 2º, porem acontece com widgets. Eu criei um widget personalizado e precisava testar, para isso eu não queria colocar na GUI final e ter que compilar o software todo cada mudança que eu fazia, então criei um projeto separado simplificado onde fiz os testes, mas isso acho que acaba sendo ruim porque as etapas de mudança eu acabo omitindo nos commit do git, pois está em outro projeto.

Esses dois últimos penso que poderia criar cada parte um folder dentro de TEST e colocar um miniProjeto. Exemplo

```
├── core/
│   ├── myMath.h
│   ├── myMath.cpp
│   ├── myVec2.h
│   └── myVec2.cpp
│              ├── Test/
│                         ├── Math /
│                                   ├── math.pro
│                                   ├── main.cpp
│                         ├── Vec2 /
│                                   ├── vec2.pro
│                                   ├── main.cpp
```

Aceito sugestões!

Answer (score 1):

A Melhor resposta infelizmente é não usar o qmake. O QMake é um pedaço antigo de código, que mal recebe manutenção, complicado de configurar por coisas fora do padrão.

O CMake eé mais indicado no momento pra qualquer projeto C++, e tem integração completa com Qt. É utilizado por todos os sistemas operacionais (inclusive windows com o visual studio) tendo virado um padrão de gerenciamento de projeto.

O CMake permite que você crie múltiplos binários / bibliotecas dentro de um único projeto (QMake também, mas de forma mais complexa), de forma que você não precisa criar vários repositórios de git com uma biblioteca só pra isso, e ele também permite compilações parciais, mudou um arquivo, compila só esse (e os que dependem dele).

Exemplo de CMakeLists pro seu projeto:

```
project(SeuApp)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

# diretorios das bibliotecas que seu codigo vai criar.
add_directory(lib)
add_directory(gui)

#diretorio do executavel, onde ta o main.cpp
add_directory(app)

#diretorio dos testes
enable_testing()
add_directory(tests)
```

E em cada pasta que você quiser ter uma biblioteca, adicionar um arquivo CMakeLists.txt, e usar o add_directory no cmake principal pra ela.

o CMakeLists.txt do app seria algo assim:

```
add_executable(MyExec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExec Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets lib gui)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim no seu `.pro`

```
QT  += core gui

QT  += widgets #caso esteja abrindo um projeto de versao antiga em versao nova

TARGET = my_App
TEMPLATE = app

include (core/core.pri)

include (gui/gui.pri)


SOURCES += main.cpp\

HEADERS += main.h\

RESOURCES += \resourcers.qrc


Na pasta gui:
crie um arquivo chamado core.pri e escreva nele

include (gl/gl.pri)

SOURCES += MainWindow.cpp\

Explorer.cpp\

.
.
.

HEADERS += MainWindow.h\

Explorer.h\

.
.
.
```

E ai vai seguindo com as demais sub-pastas...